# Why not "go to work by cars" but "go to work by car"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Ok, [this website](http://esl.fis.edu/grammar/rules/article.htm) said:

> You must put an article in front of a singular count noun.

But we got this example in [this dictionary](https://www.google.com.vn/search?q=define%20car&oq=define%20car&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2000j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8),

> Ex: we're going by car

According to the above law, **a singular count noun can not stand alone** , but we can say "**cars**" (plural count noun without article) to express "**any car or all cars**".

My question is:

is "**I go to work by cars**" wrong? or is it ok to say like that?

&

is "**I go to work by car**" idiomatic? (though it looks like wrong grammar)

Comment: In _I go to work by car_, "car" is a non-count noun, so no determiner is required

Comment: @BillJ, which dictionary says "car" is uncount noun?

Comment: You have to consider how the noun is being used. In _I borrowed a car_, "car" is a count noun, but in _I'm going by car_, it is non-count. There are many nouns in English that can be both count and non-count.

Comment: @BillJ I haven't found *car* as uncountable noun in any context

Comment: Use by+noun when refering the way someone's travel or communicate. When there is a determiner, use *in*. Please read http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/by

Comment: user178049 It refers to a means of transport, not a specific countable object. See mike's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we say **"I go to work by car"**, we are referring to 'car' as a mode of transport, rather than a subset of vehicles. As a single mode of transport, we use the singular form of the word car.

On a related note, modes of transport (by bus, by train, by car, by plane, by bicycle) don’t have an article. Which is why we don't say "I go to work by **the** car."